# C++11: defining function on std::array<char, N>

Tags: c++, c++11

`std::array` takes two template parameters:

```
typename T // the element type
size_t N // the size of the array
```

I want to define a function that takes a std::array as a parameter but only for a specific T, in this case `char`, but for any size array:

The below is malformed:

```
void f(array<char, size_t N> x) // ???
{
    cout << N;
}

int main()
{
    array<char, 42> A;

    f(A); // should print 42

    array<int, 42> B;

    f(B); // should not compile
}
```

What is the correct way to write this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a template function:

```
template<size_t N> void f(array<char, N> x) {
}
```

Comment: will this deduce the N correctly `f(A)`? or will it need to be specified `f<42>(A)`?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling Yes, it will deduce it.

Answer (score 2):

The `N` needs to be a static value. You can, e.g., make a template argument:

```
template <std::size_t N>
void f(std::array<char, N> x) {
    ...
}
```

In your example, I would still pass the argument by reference, though:

```
template <std::size_t N>
void f(std::array<char, N> const& x) {
    ...
}
```